# Accessing the intermediate layers of a tensorflow cnn model?

Tags: c#, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm new to scripting in Unity and I am doing a project that takes in video from my laptop's camera, then displays a heatmap in AR using the information in an intermediate layer from a CNN model.

I've checked out tutorials online but I haven't seen anyone discuss accessing intermediate layers from a model.

Essentially I would like to reproduce this but in Unity.

```
    intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                     outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)

    layer_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(Image)
```

Is this possible and can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers.